# Checking if a Python function referenced anything out-of-scope

Tags: python, reflection, scope

I'm exploring what's possible to do in Python and recently came across this question: after running a function, is it possible to programmatically determine whether it has referenced anything out-of-scope? For example:

```
import module1

y = 1

def foo1(x):
    return y + x  # yes - it has referenced 'y' which is out of foo1 scope

def foo2(x):
    return module1.function1(x)  # yes - it has referenced 'module1' which is out of foo2 scope

def foo3(x):
    return x*x  # no - it has only referenced 'x' which is an input to foo3, so the code executed within the scope of foo3
```

Are there some reflection / analysis tools for this? Maybe this could be achieved with the 'trace' module  somehow?

Comment: You could use `try` `except`

Comment: @NawraC could you please elaborate?

Comment: `try: foo1(x) except: print("Out of scope")`

Comment: Wait. *After running* the function, you're trying to determine whether it *actually accessed* a global or builtin? There are ways to determine whether the function *includes code* that would attempt to access variables that aren't locals, but nothing that would determine whether a function *actually accessed* a variable that wasn't local after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars):

> Get the mapping of external name references in a Python function or
> method func to their current values. A named tuple
> ClosureVars(nonlocals, globals, builtins, unbound) is returned.
> nonlocals maps referenced names to lexical closure variables, globals
> to the function’s module globals and builtins to the builtins visible
> from the function body. unbound is the set of names referenced in the
> function that could not be resolved at all given the current module
> globals and builtins.

Let's see what it returns for your examples:

**Case 1:**

```py
def foo1(x):
    return y + x  # yes - it has referenced 'y' which is out of foo1 scope

inspect.getclosurevars(foo1)
# ClosureVars(nonlocals={}, globals={'y': 1}, builtins={}, unbound=set())
```

Here it detected you are using variable in the global scope.

**Case 2:**

```py
import colorsys
def foo2(x):
    return colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*x) # yes - it has referenced 'colorsys' which is out of foo2 scope

inspect.getclosurevars(foo2)
# ClosureVars(nonlocals={}, globals={'colorsys': <module 'colorsys' from '...\\lib\\colorsys.py'>}, builtins={}, unbound={'rgb_to_hsv'})
```

Here it detected you are using a module's function.

**Case 3:**

```py
def foo3(x):
    return x*x  # no - it has only referenced 'x' which is an input to foo3, so the code executed within the scope of foo3

inspect.getclosurevars(foo3)
# ClosureVars(nonlocals={}, globals={}, builtins={}, unbound=set())
```

Here we see "nothing unusual".

Therefore, we can wrap this procedure in a function which looks if `any` of the fields (except for built-ins; i.e. `foo` can use `abs` and no problem) is non-empty:

```py
import inspect

def references_sth_out_of_scope(fun):
    closure_vars = inspect.getclosurevars(fun)
    referenced = any(getattr(closure_vars, field) for field in closure_vars._fields if field != "builtins")
    return referenced
```

Usage:

```py
>>> references_sth_out_of_scope(foo1)
True

>>> references_sth_out_of_scope(foo2)
True

>>> references_sth_out_of_scope(foo3)
False

>>> references_sth_out_of_scope(references_sth_out_of_scope) # :)
True
```

Comment: This would be a good answer, except that `inspect.getclosurevars` is buggy and reports names it shouldn't. [For example](https://ideone.com/Y6gxMI), a function `def f(x): return x.y` in a module with a `y` global variable will be incorrectly reported as accessing the `y` global.

Comment: For a bug to get fixed, someone has to put in the effort to write the fix and get it merged. No one has done that. (There are currently [two](https://bugs.python.org/issue36697) bug [reports](https://bugs.python.org/issue26577) on the tracker for this behavior, plus a [report](https://bugs.python.org/issue34947) for another issue regarding `inspect.getclosurevars`'s handling of comprehensions.)

Answer (score -1):

Check the builtin [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function. This will return a dictionary of the variables in the local scope.

```python
global_var = "Hello"

def foo():
 local_var = "world"
 if "local_var" in locals(): print(c)
 if "global_var" in locals(): print(global_var)

>>> foo()
world
```

Comment: This does not help with the problem of determining if the function accesses any variables that *aren't* local.